# ¿Como paso de un DecimalFormat(String) a Double?

Tags: java

Quiero trabajar con la parte decimal de un número, por ejemplo **123.332341** solo quiero sacar el '*.332341*' solo con 3 dígitos después del punto, así: '*.332*'
Uso el `DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat(".###");` (que encontré en internet)
hago la prueba para comprobar el resultado, y no convierte de este tipo de dato 
a double "modificado"

```
double numero = .332341;
String modificar = formato.format(numero); //debe quedar .332
double nuevo = Double.parseDouble(formato.format(modificar)); //no convierte
System.out.println(nuevo); //nada
```

¿cómo o qué otra opción puedo usar para cumplir el objetivo de traer solo 3 dígitos?
Error:

```
  Exception en Thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ",332"
    ...
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Binario.Binario.main(Binario.java:30)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para limitar el `String`de double a 3 digitos, pero usando un punto decimal, puedes usar:

```
// usar Locale.US en el formato garantiza que se usa un punto decimal en vez de un coma
String numeroString = String.format(Locale.US,"%.3f", numero);
// eso devuelve .332 para el valor que usaste
Double nuevo = Double.parseDouble(numeroString);
```

Para modificar el formato, puedes revisar la documentación [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

En tu caso no puedes instar `DecimalFormat` con el constructor que usas. Tuvieras que usar

```
df = new DecimalFormat(".###", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
```

o

```
df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
```

y luego aplicar el patron con `applyPattern()`. Si no, trabajas con tu localidad por defecto (de la maquina virtual en que corre tu programa). Eso hace tu código vulnerable para fallar si no corre en la misma localidad en que fue desarrollado.

Por si acaso que no quieres pasar por usar un `String` para cortar tu numero a 3 digitos, puedes usar `Math` también:

```
// redondear matemáticamente 
Double nuevo = Math.round(numero*1000D)/1000D;
// redondear abajo
Double nuevo = Math.floor(numero*1000D)/1000D;
// redondear arriba
Double nuevo = Math.ceil(numero*1000D)/1000D;
```

Answer (score 0):

1ero. Depende del sistema operativo que esté usando...
 El problema es el formato con el que el sistema operativo lee esta línea y el delimitador que usa. Para **solucionar** el problema, tu sistema operativo piensa que la coma delimita los decimales entonces podes hacer 2 cosas:

### Opción 1

```
double nuevo = Double.parseDouble(formato.format(modificar).replace(",","."))
```

### Opción 2

Supongo que es Windows?
Tenes que ir a - `panel de control > Reloj, idioma > Región > config adicional`.

Aquí tenes que ver el símbolo de decimal y si tiene un "`.`" cambiarlo a "`,`".

Comment: El formato de la localidad no tiene nada que ver con el sistema operativo.

Comment: Hace la prueba, si tiene que ver

Comment: Un Windows con mismo Locale va formatear igual que un Linux, BSD, MacOs, Android, Minix... lo que sea. El formato depende unicamente del Locale. Usa por ejemplo en_US y tienes un punto decimal. Haz la prueba ;)

Comment: Que yo sepa, en código, el double se define con punto decimal sin importar el OS ni el Locale de tu equipo. Si pones `double d = 3,5` no compila. Si quieres controlar todo esto, mejor usa `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: @StefanNolde También está `NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(<Locale>) DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;`. Sucede que `NumberFormat` y `DecimalFormat` brindan más poder que `String.format` como `setMinimumFractionDigits`, `setMaximumFractionDigits`, `setGroupingSize` entre otros.

Comment: Si lo sé, por eso incorporé la manera de instar DF con locale en la respuesta, después que lo mencionaste, Dudo que DF brinda más poder que `Formatter`, son más poderes distintos, y en este caso se usa una pequeña parte que los tienen en común. Pero nos pongamos copuchentos de nuevo ;)